# Material is shown only glossy on one object

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, artifacts, shader-nodes

**Solution:** Simply forgot to unwrap the object. (Select, press U, unwrap...)

I've just come to the Shading stage of some headphones I am currently modelling. However, I just can't wrap my head around one problem: I applied a downloaded PBR from polyhaven and applied it as already done in an example file provided by the creator. However, the material only looks glossy and in the designated color.
When I tried to put that same exact material on a basic cube the material looks just fine. What could be the problem here? The material nodes are exactly identical...

[image: Cube and headphones with the same material applied]

When applying the material on the whole headphones another weird thing happens, i dont know how to describe it:
[image: Material applied on the whole object]

Does anybody know what could be wrong with my object(s)?

Thank you :)

Comment: It looks like you don't have a proper UV unwrap for that mesh, or it was changed after an unwrap.

Comment: @AllenSimpson oh man thank you. I am kind of embarrassed, should have researched more and watched some more tutorials. Anyways, thank you! :)